# drupal_alter() ignores more complex function names when the hook is called

Tags: 7, hooks

I have a module named wlm that calls `drupal_alter()` as follows.

```
drupal_alter('abc', $ref, $arg1, $arg2);
```

This works perfectly for a function like the following.

```
function wlm_abc_alter(&$ref, $arg1, $arg2) { };
```

However, it breaks/does nothing if the function is similar to the following one.

```
function wlm_this_is_some_extra_detritus_abc_alter(&$ref, $arg1, $arg2) { };
```

I want to be able to call this alter function several times within my wlm module, but because the naming convention seems to be limited to `module_hook_alter()` I can only use it once, which is less than desirable. Is this an intentional design pattern; or is it a mistake; or am I just missing something obvious?

Is it possible to do something like the following, where `$my_func_name` is delivered dynamically?

```
drupal_alter($my_func_name . '_abc', $ref, $arg1, $arg2);
```

Comment: Your title is not right - Drupal ignores only inappropriately named hooks. And why can't you write everything in one function, and from inside it just call what you need to be called?

Comment: @Mołot It already exists within one function, but I'm trying to separate logic out into separate files/functions so that, in my case, designing a new "report" on our system can be done by creating a new file and not being required to adjust the existing .module file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's intentional - a module should only be able to implement a single hook once, and the naming convention requires that the function be called `modulename_hookname_alter()`. Drupal isn't ignoring your more-verbose function name, but since it doesn't match the name of the hook, it's never going to call it.

You can create other hooks though, based on whatever makes sense to your use case. For example if your module had a bunch of contexts you might create `hook_abc_CONTEXT_alter()`, and invoke it like so

```
foreach (mymodule_contexts() as $context_name) {
  $hook_name = 'abc_' . $context_name;
  drupal_alter($hook_name, $ref, $arg1, $arg2);
}
```

But I think that's as close as Drupal core will let you get to the pattern you're trying to implement.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I thought that would be the case. Your code example is exactly what I ended up doing before asking this question- I wasn't sure whether there was a better way of doing it though- I guess not!

Comment: I'm almost positive there isn't - core itself resorts to the same method with things like [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hook_form_form_id_alter&oq=hook_form_form&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3j69i61.2160j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), [`hook_query_TAG_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7), etc

Answer (score 1):

If mymodule is the short name of the module, abc is the name of the alter hook, then the implementation of that alter hook for that module is the `mymodule_abc_alter()`. Any other function of that module is not considered an implementation of that alter hook.

You could do as [drupal_prepare_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_prepare_form/7) does, however.

```
  // Invoke hook_form_alter(), hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter(), and
  // hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() implementations.
  $hooks = array('form');
  if (isset($form_state['build_info']['base_form_id'])) {
    $hooks[] = 'form_' . $form_state['build_info']['base_form_id'];
  }
  $hooks[] = 'form_' . $form_id;
  drupal_alter($hooks, $form, $form_state, $form_id);
```

In your specific case, the code would be similar to the following one.

```
drupal_alter(array('abc', 'this_is_some_extra_detritus_abc'), $ref, $arg1, $arg2);
```

If you have a function that returns you all the possible variants of that alter hook, then you could use a call like the following one.

```
drupal_alter(wml_get_abc_variants(), $ref, $arg1, $arg2);
```

In this case, `wml_get_abc_variants()` should return a string or an array containing strings.

As side note, `drupal_alter()` in Drupal 8 is deprecated in favor of `Drupal::moduleHandler()->alter()`. A Drupal service that receives the module handler as DIC, and that saves it in a property (e.g. `moduleHandler`), should use code similar to  `$this->moduleHandler->alter()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, too. I believe that for the sake of ease I'd rather go with the simpler method provided by Clive. Kudos for the D8 mention.

Comment: Keep in mind that the first argument of `drupal_alter()` can be an array; if your function returns an array, there isn't the need to use `foreach($value_from_function as $hook) { drupal_alter($hook, /* ... */); }`, since the array can be passed to `drupal_alter()` directly.